# Variadic macro with zero-args for ISO C++

Tags: c++, g++, iso, variadic-macros

I wrote this variadic macro `template<>`-maker.

```
#define TNAME0()
#define TNAME1(_1)        typename _1
#define TNAME2(_1,_2)     typename _1, typename _2
#define TNAME3(_1,_2,_3)  typename _1, typename _2, typename _3
#define TYPENAMES(_0,_1,_2,_3,n,...) TNAME##n
#define T(types...)   template< TYPENAMES(,##types,3,2,1,0)(types) >
```

It works great with GNU C++ (e.g. `T()`,`T(U)`,`T(U,V)`,...), but fails with 0 args using ISO C++ standard (calls `TYPES1` instead of `TYPES0`).

Is there a fix that works with both GNU and ISO c++?

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/KTceacfqq) on godbolt

Comment: @Brian Yes, that's the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately before C++20's `__VA_OPT__`, there is no standard-compliant way to have the preprocessor do different things with `T()` and `T(Arg)`.

Answer (score 3):

This syntax for variadic macros isn't standard C++ at all:

```
#define T(types...)
```

Instead you can use an unnamed `...`, which is referred to by `__VA_ARGS__` in the expansion. Since C++20 you can also use `__VA_OPT__(,)` to include the initial `,` only if `...` isn't empty:

```
#define T(...)   template< TYPENAMES(__VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__,3,2,1,0)(__VA_ARGS__) >
```